# Don't trigger JQuery on a disabled checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with checkboxes. When users click on label, I have custom checkbox icon that gets swapped. That works fine, but I also have disabled checkboxes in the form, and I don't wan't the click event to be triggered when you click on the disabled ones. How do I do that?

JQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox] + label').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('checkbox-pressed');
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="A"><label for="A">Option 1</label>
<input disabled type="checkbox" id="B"><label for="B">Option 2 - don't trigger JQ</label>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **`:not(:disabled)`** to select only those checkboxes that aren't disabled.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:disabled)').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Documentation: **[`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** and **[`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)**

---

You should rather use **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**. Otherwise it won't work for checkboxes that become `disabled` after the page loads up initially (say, because of some user action):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]:not(:disabled)', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but dont forget that these css selectors dont work in IE

Comment: @taylorc93 - They do from IE9 onwards.

Comment: Really? My bad, I read an article yesterday that said they didnt work in IE at all, but I guess it was outdated

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3 ... i think it's ok to start phasing out windows XP support. hah

Comment: Which doesn't work in IE? I just tested `input[type=checkbox]:not(:disabled)` in IE 7 and it works. (I have to support IE7)

Comment: What is everyone talking about? These go through jQuery, of course they work even in IE6 (assuming 1.x, not 2.x).

Comment: @Esailija - I've heard they've dropped support for IE8 and lower as of 1.8 or something, or was it 2.0. Cant remember correctly.

Comment: @techfoobar That is 2.x, you don't just do something like that in a minor version update like 1.7 -> 1.8

Comment: @Esailija - Yeah, for a sec i thought it was 1.8. Tks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:enabled`](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) selector like this:

```
$(':checkbox:enabled').click(function() {
    // Your code here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to use **:checked** in jQuery

you can find more [here](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).